# Neo4j 2.0.4 browser cannot query large datasets

Tags: neo4j, bigdata

Whenever I try to run cypher queries in Neo4j browser 2.0 on large (anywhere from 3 to 10GB) batch-imported datasets, I receive an "Unknown Error." Then Neo4j server stops responding, and I need to exit out using Task Manager. Prior to this operation, the server shuts down quickly and easily. I have no such issues with smaller batch-imported datasets.

I work on a Win 7 64bit computer, using the Neo4j browser. I have adjusted the .properties file to allow for much larger memory allocations. I have configured my JVM heap to 12g, which should be fine for 64bit JDK. I just recently doubled my RAM, which I thought would fix the issue.

My CPU usage is pegged. I have the logs enabled but I don't know where to find them.

I really like the visualization capabilities of the 2.0.4 browser, does anyone know what might be going wrong?

Comment: maybe just a feature, the build in admin visualization interface is only informative. to do advance work use advance tools http://www.neo4j.org/develop/visualize

Comment: Please add more detail.  What do the neo4j server logs say?  Is your CPU utilization pegged while querying?  What's the query you're trying to run?

Comment: Edited my original post. The query I'm trying to run is a simple MATCH n RETURN count(n). This works on the db with 1 million nodes 1500 edges, but not on the db with 1 million nodes 10 million edges.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is taking a long time, and the web browser interface reports "Unknown Error" after a certain timeout period. The query is still running, but you won't see the results in the browser. This drove me nuts too when it first happened to me. If you run the query in the neo4j shell you can verify whether or not this is the problem, because the shell won't time out.

Once this timeout occurs, you can find that the whole system becomes quite non-responsive, especially if you re-run the query, because now you have two extremely long queries running in parallel!

Depending on the type of query, you may be able to improve performance. Sometimes it's as simple as limiting the number of returned nodes (in cases where you only need to find one node or path).

Hope this helps.

Grace and peace,

Jim

Comment: I forgot to add that usually this error happens after a red bar "disconnected from server" appears. I'll edit my original comment. But yes that sounds a lot like my issue! I even made sure to LIMIT 1000. But usually my queries need to look through multiple properties.